# Simple AJAX JS works fine locally in Safari, fails on server and in Firefox (issue with evalJSON())?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, twitter, prototypejs

I wrote a script that polls Twitter via Prototype's AJAX methods, grabs JSON results, evals them and then updates a div with the formatted tweets. Everything worked fine in testing (Safari 4.0.3 on a OS 10.6.1 machine) until I loaded the script onto a server and it failed. The script had all client side items and referred to the same Prototype.js file, so I can't figure out why it was working locally but not remotely.

I stripped the script down to its bare essence -- just returning the latest tweet on my timeline into an alert box -- and works / breaks in the same way described above, and also in Firefox. I'm sure I'm making a boneheaded mistake, but can't find the error of my ways.

Here's the entirety of my page. Works locally, not on server or in Firefox:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.6.0.2/prototype.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    document.observe("dom:loaded", function(){
        var tweetAddress = "http://twitter.com/status/user_timeline/hellbox.json?count=1";
        new Ajax.Request( tweetAddress, { 
            method: 'get',
            onSuccess: function (transport) {
                var tweets = transport.responseText.evalJSON();
                alert(tweets[0].text);
            }
        });
    });
    </script> 
</head>
<body> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're hitting the "same origin policy" wall. You cannot perform an AJAX request to twitter.com from a page that's loaded from another domain.

Try JSONP instead of JSON:

http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/twitter-jsonjsonp-api-url.html

With JSON, a `<script>` tag will be injected into your page and subsequently, a callback function will be called by the loaded script. There are no domain restrictions with loading scripting from external domains.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, you are trying to do an Ajax request to the `twitter.com` domain.

If your application itself is not hosted on that `twitter.com` domain, you cannot do Ajax requests to it : you can only do Ajax requests to the domain on which your application is hosted.

This means that if your website is on "`www.mydomain.com`", you can only send Ajax requests to "`www.mydomain.com`".

Not "`test.mydomain.com`" nor "`www.anotherdomain.com`"

This is because of a security restriction implemented in web-browsers, called [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) *(quoting)* :

> the policy permits scripts running on
>   pages originating from the same site
>   to access each other's methods and
>   properties with no specific
>   restrictions — but prevents access to
>   most methods and properties across
>   pages on different sites.

A possible solution to that problem might be to use a proxy on your own domain, which would proxy to twitter.com ; this way, your website could send queries to your domain, and those would actually be re-sent to twitter ; no problem with SOP, this way.

As a sidenote, When you say "it was working locally" : do you mean you have a web-server on your local machine, and it was working when served from that server ? It shouldn't have worked, in the case.

In you mean "Opening the file locally, with something like file://.../myfile.html" in the browser's address bar -- well, maybe Safari doesn't have Same Origin Policy for local documents ?

*(Not sure about that -- just a possibility)*

Comment: Thanks Pascal -- By locally I did mean opening the file directly through the local path, and it did work. However, loading it through a localhost web server stopped the file from executing.

Comment: ok, thanks for the explanation. Loading via a local web-browser, you are encountering the SOP constraint I was speaking about, which is the "expected behavior" -- you'll either have to use a proxy, or dynamically build a script tag to do that "Ajax" request for you -- you can probably search for "JSONP" about that.